# FileCreationTime and System Time are different

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, orchestration, biztalk-orchestrations

I have been working with the application and that deals with FileCreationTime of the received file and I am facing problems. I happened to check the Tracked Message Events there I found the FileCreationTime is different for example,

I dropped the file in the receive port a 10.58 am

[image]

and FileCreationTime looks like,

[image]

why there is a change in both the time, is it a normal behavior. I think this is the reason I am facing problem.Any help is really very appreciated. Struggling with this for the past 3 days.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamps in BizTalk are always in UTC timing.  Try converting your own timezone to UTC and you 'll likely see that this is the same.